# Safari acting weird. Not loading pages and showing some Chinese text

Tags: safari

Occasionally my Safari hangs on loading a page, and after some time shows this text:

> 㰡ⴭ⁌佃䅌䥚䕒区⁅慣栠汯捡汩穡扬攠灩散攠潦⁴桥⁰慧攠楳⁭慲步搠睩瑨⁡⁣潭浥湴‭ⴾਊ㱈呍䰾਼ℭⴠ䱏䍁䱉婅剓㨠䥦⁩渠愠物杨琭瑯⵬敦琠汯捡汥Ⱐ慤搠摩爽≲瑬∠瑯⁴桥⁈呍䰠敬敭敮琮‭ⴾ਼䡅䅄㸊††㱌䥎䬠牥氽獴祬敳桥整⁴祰攽≴數琯捳猢⁨牥昽≰慧攭汯慤ⵥ牲潲献捳猢㸊††㰡ⴭ⁌佃䅌䥚䕒区⁙潵⁭楧桴⁷慮琠瑯⁣桡湧攠瑨攠景湴⁦慭楬礮⁙潵⁣慮⁡汳漠慤搠獴祬敳⁴漠潶敲物摥⁳楺敳Ⱐ整挮‭ⴾਠ†‼協奌䔾ਠ†††⁂佄夠筦潮琭晡浩汹㨧䡥汶整楣愠乥略✻紊††㰯協奌䔾ਊ††㰡ⴭ⁌佃䅌䥚䕒区⁔桥⁮數琠汩湥⁣潮瑡楮猠瑨攠灡来⁴楴汥⁴桡琠慰灥慲猠楮⁴桥⁷楮摯眧猠瑩瑬攠扡爠ⴭ㸊††㱔䥔䱅㻐鷐딠킲킴킰킻킾톁톏⃐닑雐듐뫑胐룑苐렠톁톂킾톀톖킽킺톃㰯呉呌䔾਼⽈䕁䐾ਊ㱂佄夾਼摩瘠捬慳猽≥牲潲ⵣ潮瑡楮敲∾਼摩瘠捬慳猽≩捯渢⁡汴㴢卡晡物⁉捯渢㸼⽤楶㸊㱤楶⁣污獳㴢瑥硴ⵣ潮瑡楮敲∾਼ℭⴠ浡楮⁴楴汥⁨敲攬⁲数敡瑥搠㌠瑩浥猠ⴭ㸊㱐⁣污獳㴢敲牯爭瑩瑬攠敲牯爭瑥硴ⵥ湧牡癩湧∾╀‼䄠楤㴢桥汰ⵢ畴瑯渢㸼⽡㸼⽐㸊㱐⁣污獳㴢敲牯爭瑩瑬攠敲牯爭瑥硴∾╀‼䄠楤㴢桥汰ⵢ畴瑯渢㸼⽡㸼⽐㸊㱐⁣污獳㴢敲牯爭瑩瑬攠敲牯爭瑥硴⵩湮敲⵳桡摯眢㸥䀠㱁⁩搽≨敬瀭扵瑴潮∠捬慳猽∥䀢⁈剅䘽❯灥渭桥汰ⵡ湣桯爺╀✾㰯愾㰯倾਼⽤楶㸊㱤楶⁣污獳㴢瑥硴ⵣ潮瑡楮敲∾਼ℭⴠ敲牯爠浥獳慧攠桥牥Ⱐ牥灥慴敤″⁴業敳‭ⴾ਼倠捬慳猽≥牲潲⵭敳獡来⁥牲潲⵴數琭敮杲慶楮朢㸥䀼⽐㸊㱐⁣污獳㴢敲牯爭浥獳慧攠敲牯爭瑥硴∾╀㰯倾਼倠捬慳猽≥牲潲⵭敳獡来⁥牲潲⵴數琭楮湥爭獨慤潷∾╀㰯倾਼⽤楶㸊㰯摩瘾਼⽂佄夾ਊ㰯䡔䵌㸊

Maybe someone knows what that text is? Or how to solve a problem at all?

I'll be very grateful for reply.

**P.S.** Also when some page hangs while loading and I hit refresh, it usually loads instantly. So it's now a problem with an internet connection.

Comment: Which URLs are causing this problem? How often does it happen?

Comment: @bneely it's no URL dependent, just happens from time to time with different URLs (for sure more often with those sites that auto refresh). And it happens in different places, event at work where I have a broadband internet, so it's not about internet problems. Also when some page hangs while loading and I hit refresh, it usually loads instantly.

Comment: I have no idea why it would happen, but I think it may not actually be Chinese but what can occur when utf-8 text is read as if it were utf-16

Comment: BTW I tried translating it at translate.google.com from Chinese to English, and it appeared as gibberish. Tom's theory is a good one.

Comment: @TomGewecke how can I change the encoding of that stuff? Because if I just change encoding of a webpage in Safari, it reloads the whole page, so the original content is loaded.

Comment: They are some Chinese, Japanese and Korean.  All are meaningless.  So it is meaningless to translate it with Google translation.  So I guess it is nothing with those east Asia characters.  Did u try to reset the Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters you posted are what you get if you take the text at the bottom of this post, encode it as UTF-8, and then (mistakenly) decode it as UTF-16BE.

Ultimately, Safari is decoding the data incorrectly (it should be decoded as UTF-8, but it is being decoded as UTF-16BE). It might do this for any one of several reasons:

- The server incorrectly told *Safari* to decode as UTF-16BE (e.g. via a [`charset` parameter in the `Content-Type` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#Specifying_the_document.27s_character_encoding) of the server’s HTTP response).
- The server incorrectly prepended a UTF-16BE [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) before the UTF-8 data.
- *Safari* is configured to default to UTF-16BE.
  I am not sure how this would be actually be accomplished though. The only UTF entry in the manual encoding list<sup>†</sup>  is “Unicode (UTF-8)”, which would seem to preclude forcing UTF-16BE (unlike *TextEdit* where you can actually select UTF-16BE, if you customize its list of encodings).
- *Safari* [auto-detected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charset_detection) the encoding incorrectly.

Your particular problem seems likely to be a server (or proxy<sup>‡</sup>) problem since you say that it is only happening intermittently.

The Network tab of *Safari*’s Web Inspector can show you the server response headers (to confirm or deny an erroneous `charset` parameter), but it would be probably be annoying to always have to remember to open/enable it for each tab you open (to capture the information it must already be active before when the page of interest is loaded—which may be difficult to predict if your problem is intermittent).

A packet capture could identify an erroneous BOM (and/or an erroneous `charset`), but such tools are much less convenient (also usually useless for encrypted (HTTPS) requests). If you know that the problem occurs fairly often, you might be able to send many requests through [*curl*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/curl.1.html) and try to identify erroneous BOMs/`charset`s by looking at the data it can report (server response headers and the raw content bytes).

<sup>†</sup>You can manually choose an encoding (in Safari 5.1) via the View menu’s Text Encoding submenu.
<sup>‡</sup>Such a proxy might be a [“transparent” proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy) that you might not otherwise suspect.

---

```
<!-- LOCALIZERS: Each localizable piece of the page is marked with a comment -->

<HTML>
<!-- LOCALIZERS: If in a right-to-left locale, add dir="rtl" to the HTML element. -->
<HEAD>
    <LINK rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="page-load-errors.css">
    <!-- LOCALIZERS: You might want to change the font family. You can also add styles to override sizes, etc. -->
    <STYLE>
        BODY {font-family:'Helvetica Neue';}
    </STYLE>

    <!-- LOCALIZERS: The next line contains the page title that appears in the window's title bar -->
    <TITLE>Не вдалося відкрити сторінку</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<div class="error-container">
<div class="icon" alt="Safari Icon"></div>
<div class="text-container">
<!-- main title here, repeated 3 times -->
<P class="error-title error-text-engraving">%@ <A id="help-button"></a></P>
<P class="error-title error-text">%@ <A id="help-button"></a></P>
<P class="error-title error-text-inner-shadow">%@ <A id="help-button" class="%@" HREF='open-help-anchor:%@'></a></P>
</div>
<div class="text-container">
<!-- error message here, repeated 3 times -->
<P class="error-message error-text-engraving">%@</P>
<P class="error-message error-text">%@</P>
<P class="error-message error-text-inner-shadow">%@</P>
</div>
</div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Google translation suggests that the Cyrillic `<title>` text seems to be Ukrainian for “Could not open page”.

---

The comments indicated that this text only started showing up after a software update from Apple. The exact update was probably the [10.7.3 update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5048) which added localization for several languages, including Ukrainian.

I do not have a 10.7 system, but the above content (apart from the Ukrainian `<title>` text) is largely identical to the content of files from 10.6 (*Safari* 5.1.3) with names like `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Resources/*.lproj/StandardErrorPage.html`; all these files (on 10.6 *Safari* 5.1.3) are UTF-16LE encoded with a leading (UTF-16LE) BOM. This points strongly to the second possible reason I described: the “server” (actually just a local file) is supplying content with an incorrect BOM.

If you can identify the file used for your particular localization, you can probably “fix” it. As a guess, the Ukrainian file is probably something like `…/ua.lproj/StandardErrorPage.html`.

Note: Modifying this file might break *Safari*’s “code signature”. On 10.6, the English version of this file is listed in the `…/Safari.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources` file as “optional”, so it might be okay (I have not tried it). If you do try editing/replacing the file, make a backup first! To be safe, you could make a copy of the whole `Safari.app` folder.

You can use a hex editor (e.g. [HexFiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/)) to adjust the leading BOM bytes. If you are actually dealing with a file that starts with (hex) `FE FF` (UTF-16BE BOM) and is followed by UTF-8 encoded data (i.e. the following bytes are for `<!-- LOCALIZERS:` **without** NUL (hex `00`) bytes between the characters), then you can probably just delete the first two bytes (*Safari* should then be able to auto-detect the content as UTF-8). Alternatively you could replace the leading, two-byte sequence `FE FF` with the three-byte sequence `EF BB BF` (i.e. the UTF-8 encoding of U+FEFF).

You can practice on a copy of the file if you want to try out the result before replacing the file that *Safari* actually uses. Just copy the file to your desktop (or wherever), hex edit that copy, then open it with *Safari*. After making the correct modifications (and reloading the page) you should see the Ukrainian title in the title bar and several lines of `%@` in the page itself (instead of the old page of Chinese/Korean/etc. characters).

Hopefully, Apple will fix all this in some new *Safari*/Lion update.

Comment: It seams that the problem is in Ukrainian localization. It started when Apple introduced Ukrainian localization in one of it's updates and I've switched to it. So the whole "chinese" thing was "Cannot open the page"

Comment: The same problem has been reported elsewhere for the Romanian localization.  It appears that Apple's Safari error pages for some localizations have bugs that causes this misreading as utf-16 encoding.

Comment: Major props for the detective work, Chris!